# Why Are These Tabs In Not in English

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am pretty sure my default and current languish should be English. The rest of the words in my profile is in English except for the tabs:

```
resumo respostas perguntas tags medalhas favoritos recompensas  reputação activities réplicas ...
```

And votes is in that weird languish too. It is probably Spanish but why are these tabs in Spanish or some other language, not English?

Comment: Google Translate claims it as Portuguese, which would make sense with Stack Overflow in Portuguese launching. Probably an error somewhere, I'll try to pass this on.

Comment: This was reported earlier on MSE. It seems to be a network wide thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250194/portuguese-tab-names-on-profile-page

Comment: The devs recently pushed some fixes about language "spillover" issues. Is this still happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A fix was rolled out yesterday. Hopefully for the last time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250625/155160)